# Unable to telnet to localhost from linux machine

Tags: linux, telnet

I am running a Python server on my Linux machine:

```python
# Echo server program
import socket

HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.sendall(data)
conn.close()
```

When I try to connect using telnet to above server, I get this error:

> Server lookup failure:  localhost:50007:telnet, Name or service not known

Why do I get this error, and how do I avoid it?

Comment: The problem is more likely with your use of telnet than with your code - show us exactly what command you used.  From the error message, it looks like you separated hostname and port number with `:` instead of a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python program looks alright to me.
The error from telnet looks like you have been trying to connect using an SSH-like command-line.

> $ telnet localhost:50007

Unlike SSH, Linux's telnet client does not use a : syntax to connect.

Try,

> $ telnet localhost 50007

If there were problems with your socket, telnet would return a 'connection refused' or a similar status.
You can verify if the server is properly initialized and listening to the specified port using -

> $ netstat -an | grep 50007

If netstat returns something like the line below, Your server is listening across all interfaces.

> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50007            0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN

Answer (score 0):

- Try to check `netstat -a` if your application listening on 50007 port.
- Try to use `IP 127.0.0.1` instead of ''